# how to display selected checkbox in update form angular 4

Tags: angular, forms, edit

I'm working on an update form, i want to get the previous selected checkbox in the edit form before changing it.
to display the hotel's name, I used `[value]="selectedRole.description"` in the input, and it works correctly, but I didn't know how to do it with checkbox.
changeValue is the method how change the boolean attribute 'visited' from false to true when it's selected.

```
<div *ngFor="let hotel of hotels" class="form-group">
      <h4>{{hotel.name}}</h4>
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input checkbox-dark-gray" (change)="changeValue(hotel.visited)" [checked]="hotel.visited" >
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
              <span class="custom-control-description">visited</span>
          </label>
     </div>
   </div>                                
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to remove the binding and set your field manually:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input checkbox-dark-gray" (change)="changeValue($event, hotel)" >
```

And in your component:

```
change(e, hotel) {
  /// check hotel.visited here
  /// e.target.checked is the new value
}
```